# Scatter plot with groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, scatter-plot

Hi I want to do a scatterplot or point plot of different groups.
I can get it work for individual plots but as ggplot2 need coordinates for the x-axes. thats were I already get into trouble.
This is my structure:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 33
  gene_id     gene     N1    N2    N3    N4    N5    N6    N7    T1    T2    T3    T4
  <chr>       <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ENSMUSG000… RNS     198   182   206   183   177   194   193   173   191   167   200
2 ENSMUSG000… RNS2    199   198   216   252   273   159   164   159   162   151   199
# ... with 20 more variables: T5 <dbl>, T6 <dbl>, T7 <dbl>, T8 <dbl>, T9 <dbl>,
#   T10 <dbl>, T11 <dbl>, T12 <dbl>, T13 <dbl>, T14 <dbl>, M1 <dbl>, M2 <dbl>,
#   M3 <dbl>, M4 <dbl>, M5 <dbl>, M6 <dbl>, M7 <dbl>, M8 <dbl>, M9 <dbl>, M10 <dbl>
```

I would like to plot first all individuals next to each other as well as group the N, T and Ms together and plot them in different colors. I am pretty sure I can assign the colors once the plotting itself works.

```
ggplot(a, aes(y=a[,3],x=1))+
geom_point()
```

I start in this case very low in the porcess.;;;

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transform the column names into variables. I use the data that you published but I am not sure if you expect a plot like this

```
data <- read.csv('tabla.csv')
data
```

Initial data

```
 gene_id gene  N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6  N7  T1  T2  T3  T4
1 ENSMUSG000…  RNS 198 182 206 183 177 194 193 173 191 167 200
2 ENSMUSG000… RNS2 199 198 216 252 273 159 164 159 162 151 199
```

Melt the data

```
library(reshape)

newData <- melt(data, id=c("gene_id", "gene"))
newData
```

You get a data frame like this

```
gene_id gene variable value
1  ENSMUSG000…  RNS       N1   198
2  ENSMUSG000… RNS2       N1   199
3  ENSMUSG000…  RNS       N2   182
4  ENSMUSG000… RNS2       N2   198
5  ENSMUSG000…  RNS       N3   206
```

Create a new colum with the name of each group (N, T or M)

```
count = 0
for(value in newData$variable){

        # To get the group of each value

        if(startsWith(value, 'N')){

                group <- 'N'

        }else if(startsWith(value, 'T')){

                group <- 'T'

        }else if(startsWith(value, 'M')){

                group <- 'M'
        }

        # Storing the group name into a vector
        if(count == 0){

                vectorGroup <- group
        }else{

                vectorGroup <- c(vectorGroup, group)

        }

        count <- count + 1

}

newData$group <- vectorGroup
```

Finally making the scatter plot

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(newData, aes(x = gene, y = value, color= group)) + theme_minimal() + geom_point(width = 0.5) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Paired')
```

You get a plot like this
[image: Gene by Group]

Comment: thanks. but did not change getting: Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (22021): x, y

Comment: Ok, maybe you could review if your groups are factors

Comment: not sure what you mean. but from the example above. would it be possible that you can give me an example how it might work? I tried to put the names in a different table that only contains the names, but this does not help as well. not sure if nobody had this problem before. same as well when I just name the columns 1, 2, 3....

Comment: I think I understood what the problem was. I change the code above, can you tell me if it is what you expect?

Comment: this works really beautiful. because there are so many more genes is there a way to group the colors so that its in the end just three colors? I tried: n <- c("N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5", "N6", "N7")
t <- c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7", "T8", "T9", "T10", "T11", "T12", "T13", "T14")
m <- c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10")
grouping <-c(n,t,m) but this gave me an error if I define this as the color.  in addition I killed the legend with guides(colour=FALSE) thanks again. amazing

Comment: Ok, I added a code to get the name of each group: N, T or M

Comment: maybe as a quick and naive question. renaming the columns prior melting would not help, right? why does it change to N for first 'N" value and next N column goes to ''N.1"?

Comment: I don't know if you can have many columns with the same name. I don't thinks so

Comment: never mind.thanks again. really helped a lot and I would not have been able to code this.

Comment: Your welcome. Does that mean that you original question was answered?

Comment: original question was answered great. really appreciate your support. right now the script runs on HPC. wanted to have y values on the y axes (no gene names) and groups on x axes. after first test I ended up with M30 as the only group. I think this gave me an error: ggplot(newData, aes(x = variable, y = value, color= group)) + theme_minimal() + geom_jitter(width = 0.5) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Paired')

Comment: It is because you have just a group. The correct code to plot just a group is ggplot(newData, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + theme_minimal() + geom_jitter(width = 0.5) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Paired')

Comment: but tha x=variable would be changed after the grouping code? would love to only end up at this stage with N, T and M on the x-axes. I will check and start another job on the hpc.

Comment: If your question was answered you could ***Accept it*** [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This can help others to identify the answer.

Comment: Yes, you can create different kind of graphs whenever you want. You just have to select the correct column to the x and y axes

Comment: last one gave me sttrange groups again. saving now the csv for the data frame to see what is in there. will tick answered questions ones I figured out the graph. :)