# r - assign groups based on list

Tags: r, match

I am referring to this topic:

[Scatter plot with groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819146/scatter-plot-with-groups)

Is there a way that I can create the groups from vectors

something like

```
n <- c("N1",    "N2",   "N3",   "N4",   "N5",   "N6",   "N7") 
t <- c("T1",    "T2", "T3", "T4",   "T5",   "T6",   "T7",   "T8",   "T9",   "T10",  "T11",  "T12",  "T13",  "T14") 
m <- c("M1",    "M2",   "M3",   "M4", "M5", "M6",   "M7",   "M8",   "M9",   "M10")
```

and to implement this for the decision of the groups in this code- not with startswith?

```
count = 0
for(value in newData$variable){

        # To get the group of each value

        if(startsWith(value, 'N')){

                group <- 'N'

        }else if(startsWith(value, 'T')){

                group <- 'T'

        }else if(startsWith(value, 'M')){

                group <- 'M'
        }

        # Storing the group name into a vector
        if(count == 0){

                vectorGroup <- group
        }else{

                vectorGroup <- c(vectorGroup, group)

        }

        count <- count + 1

}

newData$group <- vectorGroup
```

I am a bit puzzled. I tried the assignment with "==" or match but did not work out yet.

Thanks so much.
 Dennis

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of startWith(value, VECTORlist)... but is there a universal way?

Comment: Seems like you just want `newData$group <- substr(newData$variable, 1, 1)`. No loop needed.

Comment: though. where would I match my lists from with is it N, M or T?  Double checked the version I indicated above works. but should in general only be a match instead of "starttwith"

Comment: finally it worked with value %in% vectorlist